# Cannot connect .ned file with its .h and .cc files

Tags: omnet++

I have the following simple module 
**PythonConnection.ned**

```
simple PythonConnection {
    @class(PythonConnection);
    // my code
}
```

**PythonConnection.h**

```
#include <omnetpp.h>

class PythonConnection : public omnetpp::cSimpleModule {
    //my code
}
```

**PythonConnection.cc**

```
#include "PythonConnection.h"

Define_Module(PythonConnection);

void PythonConnection::initialize() {
    //my code
}
```

all of them are located in the same directory.

I am importing this simple module in **circles.ned** file

```
package circles;
import PythonConnection;

network circles
{
    submodules:
        python_connection: PythonConnection;
}
```

But I do not understand why I keep getting

```
A runtime error occurred:

Class "PythonConnection" not found -- perhaps its code was not linked in, or the class wasn't registered with Register_Class(), or in the case of modules and channels, with Define_Module()/Define_Channel() -- in module (omnetpp::cModule) circles (id=1), during network setup
```

when I launch the program. Could somebody help?

Comment: Does your project compile without errors?

Comment: @JerzyD. I can build the project without errors. But when I run it, I face the abovementioned problem.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I have created **General** project. To make it work, **OMNeT++ Project** is required.